# How to get time not from the System?

Tags: android, date, time

How can i get the current date and time?
Not like this way:

```
Date date = new Date();
date.getTime();

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.getTime();
```

I do not want dependency of the system clock
It's mean if the user changed the date and time on his device the app will be shown the real time and not changes?

- Do i need to use a server for this?
- The app must be connected the internet?
- There is library for this?

Comment: You can use an API (end point) from your server that returns current date and time

Comment: i use this api to do that http://www.timeapi.org/. you dont need a server there are already servers for this like the one i just posted. the app must be connected to the internet and you dont need a library, you can use the native network apis to to this

Comment: @TomerShemesh You can show some example code please?

Comment: @Anna i have added a basic example

Comment: @TomerShemesh Do i need to parse the Html by my self or can i get something like json object?

Comment: what do you mean? it is returning a json

Comment: Thank's i didn't saw the answer you post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Long>() {

    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground() {
       try { 
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl("http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now.json?" + URLEncoder.encode("\Q"));
         //gets time in UTC
          return Long.parseLong(json.getString("dateString"));
       } catch(Exception e){}
       return -1; //error
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Long date) {
           //do whatever you want with your date in your app
           //it will look like 1464039845096
    }
}.execute();
```

note you will need to add the internet permission in the manifest if you haven't already

Comment: Thank's there is a way to get the time in millisecond or just in this format?

Comment: @Anna  i have changed my example to return milliseconds

Comment: Thank you tome you the Best! are you sure JSONParser has the getJSONFromUrl method?

Comment: Illegal character in query at index 36: http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now.json?\Q ?
Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: It looks like it was been taken down